# Filessystem sizing issues on root

Tags: redhat, oracle, partition, disk-space-utilization

I recently installed a VM version of Oracle Linux 6.3 and began installing applications for testing. I realized that the "/" mount is small and the "/home" mount is way oversized, See output below.

> df -h
>
> > Filesystem                      Size      Used      Avail   Use%      Mounted on
> >
> > /dev/mapper/vg_vvfishn1-lv_root   50G          16G          32G   33%        /
> >
> > tmpfs                             7.8G         272K         7.8G  1%         /dev/shm
> >
> > /dev/xvdb1                        485M         55M          405M  12%        /boot
> >
> > /dev/mapper/vg_vvfishn1-lv_home   195G         189M         185G  1%         /home

Both root and "/home" are ext4 FS
.
How can i resize these mounts without having to reinstall the OS?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: The correct order is as follows: 

`umount /dev/mapper/vg_vvfishn1-lv_home 
e2fsck -fyv /dev/mapper/vg_vvfishn1-lv_home 
resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_vvfishn1-lv_home <SIZE> 
lvreduce -L <SIZE> /dev/mapper/vg_vvfishn1-lv_home 
e2fsck -fyv /dev/mapper/vg_vvfishn1-lv_home 
lvextend -L +<size> /dev/mapper/vg_vvfishn1-lv_root 
resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_vvfishn1-lv_root 
reboot`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to rescue mode or make sure that nothing - no user or process is accessing your /home. Use `lsof` or `fuser` to confirm.

```
umount /dev/mapper/vg_vvfishn1-lv_home
e2fsck -fyv /dev/mapper/vg_vvfishn1-lv_home
lvreduce -L -<size> /dev/mapper/vg_vvfishn1-lv_home
resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_vvfishn1-lv_home
e2fsck -fyv /dev/mapper/vg_vvfishn1-lv_home
lvextend -L +<size> /dev/mapper/vg_vvfishn1-lv_root
resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_vvfishn1-lv_root
```

Reboot

Note that lvreduce is really a troublesome command. Please back up all your data and don't be surprised if your fs goes into read-only mode because of any,anyyy silly mistake or overlooking.

Comment: Hello Soham,

thank you for this solution i will be testing it shortly. Obviously, these steps has a risk invovled with data lose. How likely is it to lose data from a installed application on /

Comment: You mean the app is generating data and storing in / - not much, risk is only with lvreduce. lvextend is fairly reliable command.

Comment: hello soham,

it worked like a charm on my test VM's with one issue, the order of the commands excuted. As you stated lvreduce is a picky command.

Comment: Glad that you did work it out. Which order did you choose. ah i see it in your comment, good job.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to boot to rescue mode, then you can shrink the /home filesystem, shrink the LV (logical volume), expand the root LV, then expand the root filesystem. Honestly though, a 50G / isn't undersized. If this were me, I'd shrink /home to have space available for database filesystems, but I wouldn't bother growing /.

Comment: I'm not sure your assertion is true anymore, From the resize2fs man page: "(As of this writing, the Linux 2.6 kernel supports on-line resize for filesystems mounted using ext3 and ext4.)."

Comment: The last time I used resize2fs, it could grow filesystems online but it couldn't shrink them online. Even if it can now (which wouldn't completely surprise me), I'm enough of a paranoiac to suggest you shrink only when unmounted anyway.